# How to create nesting models in django

Tags: python, django

Level has many questions, each question has one level. And the tree goes on from there

```
+ Level
  - Question
     + Level
         - Question
              + Level 
         - Question
              + Level 
         - Question
              + Level 
  - Question
     + Level
         - Question
              + Level 
         - Question
              + Level 
         - Question
              + Level
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models

Comment: Well you can do this by referencing, like a (binary) tree in data structures.

Answer (score 0):

you should use recursive relationship as explained here [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

example:

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
mother_level = models.ForeignKey('Level', blank=True, null=True)

enter code hereclass Level(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
mother_question = models.ForeignKey('Question', blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

add two ForeignKey to  your question model, first one to level model and 2nd ForeignKey to the question model itself, like this :

```
class Question(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',related_name='childs',null=True)
    level =  models.ForeignKey('level')
    ...
```

this way you can find the first level question by filtering questions with no parent and a specified Level instance, and then you can find each question children by:`questionInstance.childs.all()`